# How to set width for ReportViewer for MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, reportviewer

I am using [ReportViewer for MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReportViewerForMvc/) to display a report in a view in my MVC application.
How do I set width for this control?

I have set the width to 100%, but it is not working, as can be seen in this screenshot.

[image: image width]

In my view I use:

```
<div>
    @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, new { scrolling = "yes", width = "100%" })
</div>
```

And the the aspx page is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;width:100%;">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div  style="width:100%">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
<Scripts>
<asp:ScriptReference Assembly="ReportViewerForMvc"     Name="ReportViewerForMvc.Scripts.PostMessage.js" />
</Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="100%"  Height="600px"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: @johan updated the question with code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try to write the below code in your Controller

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

  ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
  reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
  reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
  reportViewer.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
  reportViewer.Height = Unit.Percentage(100);
```

Comment: Why do you set ProcessingMode to Local?  
It only works for me if I have it set to Remote.

Comment: For me width is 100% after loading is completed , but at the time of loading width is less like in the picture picpaste.com/width-VaOqaz2X.png Any idea why so

Answer (score 4):

Note: i am using ReportViewerForMvc from nuget

I found that I need to attack the width/height issue in two fronts - I added a CSS to modify the iframe in ReportViewerWebForm.aspx when it's loaded.

```css
iframe {
  /*for the report viewer*/
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The rest would be the same as the accepted answer except I removed

> reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = True

from my controller because it hides the scroll bar which I need for the wider reports I render in the same Report.cshtml which is

```html
@using ReportViewerForMvc; @{ ViewBag.Title = " Report"; }

<h2>Simple Report </h2>

@Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
```

My Controller:

```
 > 

 public ActionResult ReportByType()
        {
            var data =SomeFunction.CreateDataTable(GetReportDataFromDB());

            ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
            reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

            reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = 
              Request.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) + 
                   @"Views\Reports\ReportByType.rdlc";
            reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new 
               ReportDataSource("DataSet1", data));
           // reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = true; ---hides the scrollbar which i need
            reportViewer.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
            reportViewer.Height = Unit.Percentage(100);

            ViewBag.ReportViewer = reportViewer;
            return PartialView("Report");

        }


        enter code here
```

Comment: For me width is 100% after loading is completed , but at the time of loading width is less like in the picture http://picpaste.com/width-VaOqaz2X.png Any idea why so

Comment: Not sure. Not knowing how you wired it...(couldn't red the text in red on the pic)...maybe you should make sure a CSS sets the iframe size to be enough to show the spinner....so when you trigger the loading event, it wont look so bad. Match the colors to make it look smooth. Once loaded the report will take care of the size (100%). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ReportViewer(
     ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer,new { @width="100%"})
```